# Restricting access to user groups with Control Panel access only

Tags: templating, permissions, user-groups

I know I can restrict template output to Admins only with :

`{% if currentUser.admin ?? false %}`

…and to *any* logged in user with:

`{% if currentUser ?? false %}`

And I’m aware of `accessCp` as a [permissions handle](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/users.html#permissions).

Can I use that, or similar, to restrict template output to any user group that is allowed to access the CP – *without* having to cycle through specific user groups in the template?

I tried:

`{% if currentUser.accessCp ?? false %}`

…but that doesn't work.

I'm using Craft 3.1.29.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve figured out what I was missing. I needed to use [can](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#can):

`{% if currentUser.can('accessCp') ?? false %}`

:)